# Why has $Hom(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n})$ a vector space structure?

Tags: vector-spaces

I pulled this from [these](https://web.archive.org/web/20110410075523/http://www.extension.harvard.edu/openlearning/math222/files/notes/L3-N.pdf) notes of lecture 2 from [these](https://web.archive.org/web/20101120080741/http://www.extension.harvard.edu/openlearning/math222/) lectures, see #2 at the top of the notes where it says  "$Hom(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n})$ a vector space".

I would like some clarification as to what this means exactly. All elements of $Hom(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathbb{R}^{n})$ can be represented as $n\times n$ matrices (since it is the set of all linear transformations).

- What are the scalars of this vector space? $\mathbb{R}$?
- Can these matrices just be thought of as $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, where these are the elements of the vector space?

Comment: Yes for both questions.

Comment: @Crostul, thank you very much! :)

Comment: More generally, for any two vector spaces $V,W$ over the same field $F$, the space $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ is also a vector space over $F$.